# Contraction of tensor?

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

Given the the tensor

$T_{\alpha, \beta...\gamma}=(-1)^n \nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta...\nabla_\gamma{1\over r_{ab}} $

where $n$ is the rank of the tensor, how does one get to the likes of $T_\alpha={{(r_{ab})_{\alpha}}\over {r_{ab}^3}}$? I understand that $T={1\over r_{ab}}$, since that is just eliminating all of the covariant derivatives and leaving the $r$ term, but what about $T_{\alpha}$?

Furthermore, how does one get from $T_\alpha$ to $T$? Is it something to do with contraction?

I'm quite rusty on tensor calculus.

(Found in Computer simulations of liquids D. J. Tildesley and M.P. Allen pg 14)

Comment: Looks like $T$ is a function. Here $T_\alpha$ is iust the usual derivative. You can only get $T$ fron its derivatives up to constants

Comment: wouldn't that make $T_\alpha={(r_{ab})_\alpha \over {2r_{ab}^2}}$?

Comment: If its just a function, $T_\alpha = \frac{-(r_{ab})_\alpha}{ r_{ab}^2}$ without more information i cannot tell what is wrong.

Comment: Ah yes my bad, the book says that $T_\alpha={ (r_{ab})_\alpha \over {r_{ab}^3}}$, so I'm at a loss really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r_{ab}$ is probably the distance between a pair of particles for an interaction or something. In general, for the position vector $\mathbf{r}$ and $r=|\mathbf{r}|$, we have $$\nabla\frac{1}{r}=-\frac{1}{r^2}\nabla r=-\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}$$

If we offset the origin with $\mathbf{r_p}$ we get

$$\nabla\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_p|}=-\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_p}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_p|^3}
$$
And so on.

So it seems $T_\alpha$ is just the components with index $\alpha$ of $\nabla\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}_b|}=-\frac{\mathbf{r}_a-\mathbf{r}_b}{r_{ab}^3}$